# Pressure at the foot of ocean waves?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

If I'm surfing a 100 ft wave and temporarily dip my finger into the water near my surfboard ..would it experience the pressure due to the whole water column or is there some other principle of hydrodynamics which I'm forgetting to apply..?

Also if the pressure is indeed p = ρ g h..then there would certainly be a certain hypothetical height of the wave (h)..(like the 'waves not mountains' scene in the movie interstellar) where I would be unable to even dip my finger because of the huge opposing pressure inside..the wave's foot being equivalent to a solid on touching..:|

Comment: Re, "dip my finger...near my surfboard," Isn't your surf board supposed to be somewhere close to the _surface_ of the water?  Maybe a better question would be, what signal would be sent by a pressure-transducer that was anchored to the bottom as the wave passed overhead?

Comment: @Solomon Slow : okay..transducer it is.So, what would be the pressure now recorded by the transducer ?

Comment: Hey Amy! What you actually feel when sticking your hand into the moving water is not pressure but a **force**, this force is a combination of **static pressure** and the amount of specific force that emerges from the fluid being disturbed by your finger, the so called **dynamic pressure**. First things first: Static pressure acts uniform in all directions and can be the result of constraining a fluid (e.g. compressed air bottle) or the result of a high fluid column above that presses on you.

Comment: The earth with its mass attracts you but also lighter things like gases. The further away you go away from the surface the lower this force gets (imagine drawing larger spheres around the earth surface, the larger the sphere gets, the larger its surface and thus the smaller the force acting on a particular part of it). As a result there will be a lower density of gas particles further away. Nonetheless all these gas particles are attracted to the center of the earth, and they press down on particles that are below them.

Comment: This creates this static pressure. This pressure depends on the column above you as well as how heavy the fluid (gas or liquid is): $p_{static} = \rho g h$. If you fly with an airplane the pressure outside of the airplane is significantly lower than when standing on earth. The reason you do not feel it is that some clever engineer came up with a solution to pressurize the airplane and make it feel like on earth. Similarly if you would dive under water, the water column above $\rho_{water} g h_{water}$ as well as the air column above the water $\rho_{air} g h_{air}$ will act on your body.

Comment: That is first effect, it does not depend on your velocity but is everywhere the same. The second effect is as already mentioned the dynamic pressure. Imagine somebody throwing a ball at you and you catch it. What you feel is a force, the harder the other person throws the ball at you the higher this force will be. Any moving fluid is like a bunch of such basketballs, they are super small but can be really fast. What you feel when sticking your hand out of a moving car is not the static pressure but instead only a result of the dynamic pressure.

Comment: In front of your hand the gas particles will be brought to stop and will transfer most of their momentum onto your hand and additionally the static pressure will act on your hand, while behind there will only be the static pressure. You see dynamic pressure is directed, it does not act on all sides equally such as static pressure. I think now you should be able to give the answer to your question by yourself. :)

Comment: @2b-t: thank you for your answer : ) so it means that the base of a 100 foot wave really would have crushing pressure as a combination of static + dynamic.

Comment: @Amy.fosters1729 What pressure precisely you feel really depends on what you are doing: In case you are standing still and the wave hits you, you will feel the dynamic pressure on the impact, similar to doing a belly flop from around $1.3 m$ or $4 ft$ (assuming the wave travels with $5 \frac{m}{s}$ or around $11 mph$ due to $\frac{m v^2}{2} = m g h$). After the impact you will start to move with the wave. Inside the wave and moving along with it you won't feel any dynamic pressure, you will feel though the static pressure above you that should be as high as diving $100 ft$ below the surface.

Comment: @2b-t :okay..:) so that means that the pressure inside the wave ( while moving along with it ) is equivalent to 100 ft  worth of water column..but in that case  pascal's law of equal pressure at all points on the same hoz line is violated since along that line (if we extend it) the rest of nearby regions are only experiencing pressure due to atm and a few inches of water..but this is a dynamic situation and that law is for static scenarios..right ? I sound quite nutty right now :).but  was just thinking about this stuff while watching a video of surfers riding giant waves in nazare(portugal)

Comment: @2b-t also..if i may ask..what could be the situation at the boundary of water air interface in such a wave,,because the boundary molecules of outer +front layer have to have the same pressure as the water molecules a few feet behind them and at the same depth below the wave's top... would they not resist any penetrating force/pressure (like me dipping in my unfortunate finger) with a huge pressure..surface tension can be neglected here...and it would be weird physics to push my hand through the curtain and suddenly experience force due to an additional 3 atm (100 ft of water =3 atm)

Comment: @Amy.fosters1729 Pascal's law only holds for confined static fluids. In such a case the fluid above presses the fluid below downwards but also to the side, as on the side there are walls (as long as they resist the corresponding pressure) they will press back on the fluid and this will result in an isotropic (uniform in all directions) pressure.

Comment: In the case of a wave this is all very differently: The fluid column (wave) above will try to press the particles below down and to the sides but these will start moving. As a consequence the pressure distribution will be distorted such as can been seen in [this figure](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Snapshots-of-SPH-results-case-C-of-wave-breaking-and-pressure-distribution-at-time_fig8_261018238). You won't instantly feel the higher pressure of the fluid column above (like a curtain) but you will feel it in the center.

Comment: Nazare is really nice. :) I really like [this picture](https://i0.wp.com/www.surfer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Nazare_PraiaDoNorte_Opener_Grambeau.jpg?resize=1200%2C801&ssl=1).

Comment: And yes.nazare is beautiful.the word literally means " beautiful sight " in urdu.but that is not the etymology for the name of this portugese city.on wiki it says they are referring to nazareth( bible)

Comment: @ 2b-1t ohhh ..alright :) I kind of get it now...I did not study this in the undergrad hydrostatic course.but makes sense to me after you explain it .the  picture really cleared it up for me.thanks a lot  : )

Answer (score 0):

$P = \rho g h$ is true in static situations.  Your wave example is dynamic and pressures at a given height may not be uniform in such cases.

If the water just below the surface did actually have a very high pressure, that pressure would rapidly accelerate the water until the pressure equalized.  It wouldn't form a barrier to entry.

Comment: @BowlOfRed- thank you for taking the time to answer :)..but one thing comes to mind   
 Roughly, what would be the value of the water pressure at the foot of an ocean wave and at some distance away from the wave-atmosphere interface(like if i dipped my whole surfboard inside then say at its tip).Which equation would hold considering the wave is  around 100 ft high (a demonic rogue wave haha ) and travels at say, 20 knots i.e around 36kph.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-017j-design-of-electromechanical-robotic-systems-fall-2009/course-text/MIT2_017JF09_ch06.pdf has some equations around ocean wave pressure.   To a first approximation, the pressure is equal everywhere at the surface (= 1atm) and increases with depth.  It's just that over the tall part of the wave, the pressure increases less rapidly so that it all evens out as you descend.